# how to download file in ajax success using laravel response

Tags: ajax, laravel, file, download, response

i am making a zip file of PDFs and then download it in browser.. i have used ajax and want to receivce file in response so that i can download it.

```
return response()->download(public_path().'/documents/'.$zipName , $zipName, $headers);
```

[this is the response i m getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ryw6X.png)

i have also tried this method but it didn't worked idont know what i am missing.

Laravel Response:

```
  $downloadData = [
          'zipFile' => $zipName,
          'headers' => $headers,
          'url' => public_path('documents/').$zipName
        ];
        return response()->json(['status'=>1,'data'=> $downloadData]);
```

AJAX success:

```
  var a = document.getElementById('zipDownload');
                       a.href  = data.data.url;
                       a.target  = '_blank';
                       a.download  = data.data.zipFile;
                       setTimeout(function() {
                         a.click();
                       }, 200);
```

the anchor is showing correct path for the file and downloads when i paste that in a new tab.. but when i trigger the anchor tag it shows
Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/ems/public/documents/records-20200512002210.zip

Comment: could you try `header('Content-Type: ' . mime_content_type($filepath));` above `response()->download()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this in the Laravel response (if you are accessing the web app using http://localhost:8000 or something similar, where the laravel app's public directory is set as the document root):

```
 $downloadData = [
          'zipFile' => $zipName,
          'headers' => $headers,
          'url' => '/documents/'.$zipName
        ];
return response()->json(['status'=>1,'data'=> $downloadData]);
```

Here you may even use the `url('/documents/'.$zipName)` or `route()` functions depending on the configurations/environment variables that have been set.

`file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/ems/public/documents/records-20200512002210.zip` is a file resource that is on the webserver, and the front-end (JS) should not see it. 
So, the zip file that you are going to download should be accessed relative to the web application's URI.

In your case, if the browser is able to access something like `http://localhost:8000/documents/<zip file name>.zip` or `http://localhost/ems/documents/<zip file name>.zip`, then you're good to proceed further.